# magento local development on wamp

Tags: magento, wamp

i have a development copy of my store and anytime I try to add a product to my cart, i get an error like this:

> INDX(  §3!<(è ètÎ§t.Î‡}    p^êÀ§bÈ%PÎbÈ%PÎ¼’   õÕ~Î¼’  õÕ~Î€˜z System.Net.dll.7‚   xdêÀ§X^¿Ö~Îº¿ÁÖ~Îº¿ÁÖ~ÎX^¿Ö~ÎP F System.Net.ni.dll 5‚   p\êÀ§ÄZ’Ö~Î&¼”Ö~Î&¼”Ö~ÎÄZ’Ö~Îpf System.ni.dlle.…} ˜‚êÀ§bÈ%PÎbÈ%PÎZ1õÕ~ÎZ1õÕ~Î°À  System.Runime.Serialization.dllfQ‚T˜ˆêÀ§Ló-Ö~Î®T0Ö~Î®T0Ö~ÎLó-Ö~Î ˜ #System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll‰}€pêÀ§bÈ%PÎbÈ%PÎôõÕ~ÎôõÕ~Îð¨æ System.ServiceModel.dll<ƒˆvêÀ§ú`Ö~Î\Â Ö~Î\Â Ö~Îú` Ö~Îp l System.ServiceModel.ni.dlll‹}  ˆxêÀ§bÈ%PÎbÈ%PÎ€UõÕ~€UõÕ~Î ° System.ServiceModel.Web.dlle‚~êÀ§0ÌXÖ~Î0ÌXÖ~Î0ÌXÖ~Î0ÌXÖ~Î°¨ System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll¥²ÉPˆvêÀ§bÈ%PÎbÈ%PÎ ºôÕ~Î ºôÕ~Î°ú System.Windows.Browser.dll²„^|êÀ§è6^ Ö~Îè6^ Ö~Îè6^ Ö~Îè6^ Ö~Îðä System.Windows.Browser.ni.dllÌ¥xfêÀ§bÈ%PÎbÈ%PÎÆÞ ôÕ~ÎÆÞ ôÕ~Îp h System.Windows.dlltÙ‚€lêÀ§˜NÎÖ

followed by this stack:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function saveAttributeData() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\localdevsite\app\code\core\Enterprise\Customer\Model\Observer.php on line 86
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  162576  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0080  349224  Mage::run( )    ..\index.php:86
3   0.0200  1004104 Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ) ..\Mage.php:683
4   1.9282  7392840 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( )  ..\App.php:354
5   1.9452  7613744 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( )   ..\Front.php:176
6   1.9522  8053616 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:250
7   2.2102  10787248    Zeon_Customcheckout_CartController->addAction( )    ..\Action.php:419
8   5.2795  20007880    Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save( )   ..\CartController.php:145
9   6.1246  26354824    Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->save( ) ..\Cart.php:465
10  6.1246  26354848    Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save( )   ..\Quote.php:1898
11  6.2006  26485984    Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_afterSave( )   ..\Abstract.php:319
12  6.2006  26486072    Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave( ) ..\Quote.php:324
13  6.2006  26486704    Mage::dispatchEvent( )  ..\Abstract.php:466
14  6.2006  26486704    Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent( )   ..\Mage.php:447
15  6.2016  26498584    Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod( ) ..\App.php:1317
16  6.2016  26498584    Enterprise_Customer_Model_Observer->salesQuoteAfterSave( )  ..\App.php:1338
```

everything else is working on the site so far, and these products work on the production server.  I'm guessing something is wrong in my wamp setup?  does anyone know where I could start looking?

Comment: Are you sure you are not running through IIS?

Comment: i've checked i don't see IIS installed on my system.  any ideas what I could try to check?